# initWithStyle:CGRectZero sending 'const CGRect' to parameter of incompatible type

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm working with this chunk of code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:nil] autorelease];
}
//cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
```

and first replaced

```
initWithFrame:
```

with

```
initWithStyle:
```

above, because I was getting a `initWithFrame:reuseIdentifier deprecated` error.

But, now I am getting a new error:

```
Sending 'const CGRect' (aka 'const struct CGRect') to parameter of incompatible type 'UITableViewCellStyle' (aka 'enum UITableViewCellStyle').
```

This error is pointing specifically at the `CGRectZero` in `initWithStyle:CGRectZero` above.

I've searched and can't figure this one out. Anyone know how to fix this?
Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Have you actually read the error message and tried to understand it????  (And have you looked at the documentation for UITableViewCell????)

Answer (score 0):

The `style` argument must be one of the [`UITableViewCellStyle` enumeration values](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UITableViewCellStyle):

```
typedef enum : NSInteger {
   UITableViewCellStyleDefault ,
   UITableViewCellStyleValue1 ,
   UITableViewCellStyleValue2 ,
   UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
} UITableViewCellStyle;
```

If you look closely, you will discover that `CGRectZero` is not in the list.  In general, when you change a statement to send a different message, you should expect to need to change the values you pass as the message's arguments.